# Electric Field due to a Dipole

Tags: electromagnetism

I have read on my physics book that the electric field due to an electric dipole varies as $1/r^3$ and I have also seen the for it . But how can I physically understand the $1/r^3$ nature of the field?

Comment: How did you physically understand the $1/r^2$ nature?

Comment: It's just the emperical law by Coulomb

Comment: Well then it is just the mathematical build up from the law for $1/r^3$. Or am I not understanding your question?

Comment: Yes it is mathematical build up. But can we related it physically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field of an arbitrary localized charge distribution can be expanded as a Laurent series in inverse powers of the distance: $1/r^2$, $1/r^3$, $1/r^4$, etc. This is called a [multipole expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion).

The total charge or “monopole moment” gives the strength of the $1/r^2$ term. The “dipole moment” is related to the strength of the $1/r^3$ term. The “quadrupole moment” is related to the strength of the $1/r^4$ term. The “octupole moment” is related to the strength of the $1/r^5$ term. Etc.

What introductory treatments call “a dipole” — two equal and opposite charges, in the limit that their charge goes to infinity while their separation goes to zero — is simply an idealized charge distribution where only the $1/r^3$ term happens to be nonzero.

The multipole expansion is usually expressed on terms of the potential rather than the field. That expansion starts with a $1/r$ monopole term and a $1/r^2$ dipole term.

The key mathematics behind it is the identity

$$\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}’|}=\frac1r\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\left(\frac{r’}{r}\right)^\ell P_\ell(\cos\gamma)$$

where $P_\ell(x)$ is a [Legendre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) and $\gamma$ is the angle between the vectors $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r}’$. (Legendre just expanded the left side for $r\gg r’$ and found that the terms involved polynomials in $\hat{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{r}}’$, which have come to be named after him.)

Using this expansion in the integral for the potential of an arbitrary charge distribution,

$$\varphi(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int\frac{\rho(\mathbf{r}’)d^3\mathbf{r}’}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}’|},$$

gives one kind of multipole expansion for the potential.

The physical significance of the dipole moment is that if the net charge (i.e., the monopole moment) is zero, then the dipole term in the multipole expansion is the *dominant* term at a large distance away: the additional terms terms are negligible in comparison as $r\to\infty$. In other words, you can approximate any charge distribution that is overall neutral as a dipole at large distances.

Answer (score 4):

A quick-and-dirty way of seeing why the fall-off rate should be $r^{-3}$ is as follows:  Suppose you are at a point $P$ on the $x$-axis, a distance $r$ from the origin.  There is a positive charge $+q$ at the origin, and a negative charge $-q$ at $x = d$.  What is the total field?

The field from the positive charge is $E_x = q/r^2$, and the field from the negative charge is $E_x = - q/(r+d)^2$.  Define $f(r) = q/r^2$.  Then the total electric field is
$$
E_x = f(r) - f(r+d) = - d \left(\frac{f(r+d) - f(r)}{d} \right) \approx - d f'(r)
$$
in the limit where $d$ is sufficiently small.  But $f'(r) = - 2 q /r^3$, so $E_x \approx - 2 q d / r^3$.

The main idea here is that the fields of the positive and negative charges *almost* cancel out (but not quite);  and the lack of cancellation between them is due to the slight difference in their distances.  But the difference in any function (such as the electric field) due to a small difference in its argument (such as the distance) can be approximated by the derivative of that function.